# How to add data to a vector in a apply function?

Tags: r

I have an object like this:

```
str(sequ[1:2])
 $ gi|254574545|ref|XM_002494337.1|:Class 'SeqFastadna'  atomic [1:3288] a t g a ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "name")= chr "gi|254574545|ref|XM_002494337.1|"
  .. ..- attr(*, "Annot")= chr "gi|254574545|ref|XM_002494337.1| Pichia pastoris GS115 ER membrane protein involved in regulation of OLE1 transcription, acts w"| __truncated__
 $ gi|254574543|ref|XM_002494336.1|:Class 'SeqFastadna'  atomic [1:1614] a t g g ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "name")= chr "gi|254574543|ref|XM_002494336.1|"
  .. ..- attr(*, "Annot")= chr "gi|254574543|ref|XM_002494336.1| Pichia pastoris GS115 Subunit of the CCR4-NOT complex (PAS_FragD_0003) mRNA, complete cds"
```

How can I concatenate all the data of the names: `"gi|254574545|ref|XM_002494337.1|" "gi|254574543|ref|XM_002494336.1|"`?

I do it like this:

```
library(seqinr)
sequ = read.fasta(file="../pure_fasta_pichia.fasta", strip.desc = TRUE)
seq_genome = c()
for (i in 1:length(sequ)){ 
  seq_genome = c(seq_genome, sequ[[i]][1:length(sequ[[i]])])
}
```

I am convinced that it can be done with lapply or similar.

And I tried this:

```
seq_genome = c()
seq_genome = lapply(sequ, function(x){seq_genome = c(seq_genome, x)})
```

I expected to have:

```
seq_genome 
 a t g a ... a t g g ...
```

My data is quite big (`>length(sequ)  [1] 4903`) and each one is more than 200 elements, usually 3k of elements. That's why my computer crashed and I don't copy a `dput` here.

How can I do it ? I think my function inside `lapply` is not right but I don't know how to improve it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for `lapply` here. Your problem is how you import the data. You need `as.string = TRUE`, then you can simply concatenate a `list` using `do.call` and `c`.

```
# Some package data
dnafile <- system.file("sequences/malM.fasta", package = "seqinr")

# Use as.string = TRUE
x <- read.fasta(file = dnafile, as.string = TRUE)

# Only one fasta entry in this file, so make multiple copies for example
x <- setNames( c( x , x , x ) , letters[1:3] )

# Concatenate and collapse into single sequence (remove str() call - for display purposes)
str( paste0( do.call( c , x ) , collapse = "" ) )
# chr "atgaaaatgaataaaagtctcatcgtcctctgtttatcagcagggttactggcaagcgcgcctggaattagccttgccgatgttaactacgtaccgcaaaacaccagcgacgcgccagccattccat"| __truncated__
```

Comment: This way I get just the sequence for each entry but it doesn't concatenate the sequences of out[1], out[2], out[i] into just one sequence. But at least finally I understood how the do.call works!

Comment: oh, in that case `paste0( out , collapse = "" )`

Comment: It is what I was about to write :D